MS-domain: Some SRV-records not working thru resolver
Hi all!
I'm trying to fix this problem for several months now. We are using Cisco Umbrella as DNS protection, but when using it's DNS server, my endpoints wont work properly. Because of that, we are not using the service since January.
Cisco and our MSP are clueless, and blame the domain ( as you'll soon see )
I'd love your help to understand what might cause it.
The setup:
I'm running 2019-level domain, "domain2000A.corp" with two DCs, both running DNS servers:

10.0.0.3
10.0.0.4

Each has secondary IP address, because they replaced old DCs:

10.0.0.1
10.0.0.2

I also have two Umbrella VA resolvers, at

10.0.0.10
10.0.0.20

It all worked fine, for over two years!
The problem:
When setting up a computer's DNS to work with the DC, then restart it, everything works as expected.
When changing the DNS server ( under ncpa.cpl ) to the VA, then restart it - it'll:

Take some minutes to turn on, seeing blue loading-screen saying "waiting for GPO". eventually timeout
Wont list remote/domain-users under groups ( it will only show SID, but not the users names )
I saw in the event log "SERVFAIL" for srv _ldap._tcp.default-first-site-name._sites.dc._msdcs.domain2000A.corp

But again - when I change the DNS server to the DC, then restart - it all works again!
So.... what am I lookin for here?
I've reached a wall, and after several months of troubleshooting with Cisco support, it'd really seem to be a problem with the DC.
What would you test next?
How could a windows DNS server decide not to supply answers to one machine but not the other?

What DNS traffic does the DC see from the Cisco system? (Both in general, and also specifically whether DNSKEY queries are being made – one problem with a fake domain name is that it needs manual DNSSEC trust anchor setup, otherwise the VA will likely honor the "non-existence proof" that the public DNS has for your domain...)

@grawity_u1686 Both DCs are the authoritative DNS server, arent' them? Is it only one of them? Also - we've tried to set the VA to work with each DNS-server individually, and it kept failing. I mean.... one of them has to be the authoritative-DNS-server... Do you think that's still related?

Yes, they're both authoritative (as they directly host the zone), but that's completely besides the point – the whole reason DNSSEC exists is that resolvers can't blindly trust a server's claim that it is "authoritative" for the zone, they want to verify each reply. (The resolver queries the parent zone for NS and DS records of .corp, and either it gets the signed data or it gets a likewise signed "proof of absence".) So I still believe it's the most likely cause, unless you investigate and verify that it is not the cause.

Thank you for the reply! I will absolutley try that. Sorry if I'm being a total newb, but how would you chech such a thing? Just gimme a sentense in English so I could look up further haha DNSSEC is a huge area and I'm not that good with Windows Server
